Google Play Update Rejected Due to Hard Paywall – No Login or Demo Accounts
We are facing repeated rejections from Google Play when attempting to release our app. The issue is due to a hard paywall with a free trial. Our app does not have any login or account system, therefore we cannot provide login details or demo accounts as requested by Google Play.
Context:

The app has a hard paywall with a free trial for users.
We do not use any login/account system.
Under the App Access section, Google Play reviewers mention they are unable to:

Use free trials to access the app.


In the Google Play Academy, it states:

“You need to provide access details to a demo account that doesn't require payment or payment details.” -
However, providing access details is not possible since we don’t have any form of login or user accounts.



Is there an acceptable workaround for apps with hard paywalls but no login/account system?
Would implementing app links or deep links to bypass the paywall and grant reviewers access be a viable solution?
This feels hacky and could introduce vulnerabilities, as well we’re not sure if it aligns with Google Play policies.
What is the best approach to comply with Google Play’s requirements without redesigning our app’s core functionality (e.g., adding an account system)?

FIrst; this question is off topic for stackoverflow. Second you need to provide them some way to review your app, how you do that is up to you

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/115145

Thank y for letting me know. What would be a better place to post this?
